# Dynamic list in ANSI C?

Tags: c

Am i right in thinking the only way to create a list which grows during run time in C, is to use a linked list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linked list is one way. It has `O(1)` insertion (assuming you're already at the insertion point) and deletion, but `O(n)` `n`'th element lookup.

Resizing a dynamically allocated array with `malloc` is another. It has `O(1)` `n`'th element lookup but `O(n)` insertion (due to having to copy all later elements after the insertion point, and possibly all elements on `realloc`) and deletion.

If you're really worried about performance for both these operations, I would go with some sort of self-balancing tree structure. You can surely attain `O(log n)`for lookup, insertion, and deletion. And for all practical purposes if objects are in main memory, `log n` is bounded by 32 or 64 and `O(log n)` might as well be `O(1)`.

Comment: Im only really doing insertion at the end and then traversal, no insertions in the middle and no deletions.

Comment: Then a simple linked list should be perfect.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a combination of malloc and realloc.  To first initialize a C array (malloc) and to grow it (realloc).  However, you won't want to grow it by 1 element at a time if you are doing a lot of inserts.  It's best to come up with a scheme to make the list grow as you need it (ie add 10 elements each time the list size reaches the allocated size).

Answer (score 1):

I've made a list using malloc and realloc that can grow dynamically. I don't have the most recent code available at this moment, but here is some (incomplete, but functional) code that I wrote a while back to manage dynamic, generic, lists in C.

```
#include<stdbool.h>

struct empty_list_key{
    int offest;
    struct empty_list_key* next;
};

typedef struct list_t{
    int CURRENT_POSITION; //position of the array cursor.
    int BLOCK_SIZE; //size of data type
    int SIZE;
    void** data;
    struct empty_list_key* empty_keys;
}list_t;

list_t* init_list(int size, int blocksize){
    if(size < 0){
        return NULL;
    }
    list_t *list = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    if(list == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    list->CURRENT_POSITION = 0;
    list->BLOCK_SIZE = blocksize;
    list->SIZE = size;
    list->data = malloc(sizeof(void*) * size);
    if(list->data == NULL){
        free(list);
        return NULL;
    }
    if(size > 0){
        int i;
        struct empty_list_key* empty_key;
        empty_key = malloc(sizeof(struct empty_list_key));
        //TODO: Check for NULL. If NULL, cleanup everything and return.
        empty_key->offest = 0;
        if(size > 1){
            for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
                empty_key->next = malloc(sizeof(struct empty_list_key));
                //TODO: Check for NULL. If NULL, cleanup everything and return.
                empty_key = empty_key->next;
                empty_key->offest = i;
            }
        }
    }else{
        list->empty_keys = NULL;
    }
    return list;
}

void delete_list(list_t* list){
    free(list->data);
    free(list);
}

bool list_set(list_t* list, int pos, void* value){
    if(pos < list->SIZE && pos >= 0){
        list->data[pos] = value;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
bool list_unset(list_t* list, int pos){
    if(pos < list->SIZE && pos >= 0){
        free(list->data[sizeof(void*) * pos]);
        list->data[pos] = NULL;
        struct empty_list_key* empty_key = malloc(sizeof(struct empty_list_key));
        if(empty_key == NULL){
            return false;
        }

        //insert empty key at beginning of empty keys linked list.
        empty_key->offest = pos;
        empty_key->next = list->empty_keys;
        list->empty_keys = empty_key;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void* list_get(list_t* list, int pos){
    if(pos < list->SIZE && pos >= 0){
        return list->data[pos];
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

bool list_push(list_t* list,void* value){
    void** tmp = realloc(list->data,(sizeof(void*) * list->SIZE) + sizeof(void*));
    if(tmp == NULL){
        return false;
    }else{
        list->data = tmp;
        list->SIZE ++;
        list_set(list,list->SIZE-1,value);
        return true;
    }
}

void* list_pop(list_t* list){
    void* value = list_get(list,list->SIZE-1);
    void** tmp = realloc(list->data,(sizeof(void*) * (list->SIZE ) ));
    if(tmp == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        list->SIZE --;
        list->data = tmp;
        return value;
    }
}

int list_size(list_t* list){
    return list->SIZE;
}

bool list_add(list_t* list, void* value){
    if(list->empty_keys == NULL){
        return list_push(list,value);
    }else{
        int offset = list->empty_keys->offest;
        struct empty_list_key* empty_key = list->empty_keys->next;
        free(list->empty_keys);
        list->empty_keys = empty_key;
        return list_set(list,offset,value);
    }
}

bool list_remove(list_t* list, int pos){
    struct empty_list_key* empty_key = malloc(sizeof(struct empty_list_key));
    if(empty_key == NULL)   return false;

    if(list_unset(list,pos)){
        empty_key->offest = pos;
        empty_key->next = list->empty_keys;
        list->empty_keys = empty_key;
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [utlist](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/utlist.html) and [utarray](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/utarray.html). utlist is basically a linked list and utarray is malloc/realloc macro. You can easily make them as inline func.